# Wifi/Network disappeared completely

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, system-installation, network-manager

Ubuntu 20.04 user here. When I got to the settings, there is no "wireless" or "wifi" option there. Even the drop down menu at the top right corner no longer shows the Wifi icon. I have no access to the internet now. I'll put down some commands and their out puts.

```
$iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp2s0    no wireless extensions.
```

```
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520] (rev 07)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 21)
00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
01:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330 / M430 / Radeon 520 Mobile] (rev 81)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 07)
```

`dmesg` output is long so I've put it [here](https://textdoc.co/l1id5tOVKGug0Aej)

Apparently, it has been showing me some firmware warnings that I've been ignoring for a while but my other laptop also running 20.04 also shows that but no network/wifi issues there. But today only, it also has been showing me some Radeon ring in directory '0' or '1' which was new. It would stuck at that when shutting down the pc or restarting.

I haven't updated both my laptops in 3+ months. You all will probably give me some commands to run, some of those would need installation from the apt store which isn't possible for me without the internet. My only viable option seems to be to install a different OS. I could chose to re-install Ubuntu, but since it's Ubuntu again so I'm afraid that ai might bump into the same problem again. I'm thinking of Linux Mint, but at this point I'm so comfortable with Ubuntu that ai don't want to switch. So, I have 3 options, either re-install Ubuntu 20.04, install 22.04 or just install a different OS like Linux Mint that I'm not comfortable with.

Even my WiFi has no internet access so I'd wait until it gets back online or just use my mobile internet to download a fresh iso and hope the OS installation fixes the issue.

Comment: Connect to WiFi with your phone and connect your phone to your laptop with USB and enable USB tethering, then a sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade may help in solving the issue or bring you more convenience trying to figure out how to solve the issue :)

Comment: @Amirreza I don't know how but the wifi is back. My laptop was unresponsive. I kept on pressing the power key and it eventually turned on. I saw the WiFi was there just fine. I've stumbled upon these kinds of problems on my laptop frequently. It creates problems on its own and fixed them on its own a while later. Although the specs are alright, but after 6 years of usage, i think it's getting old. Thanks a lot for your suggestion, I was going to try that. Either way, now I will update it. But it may happen again. I'll ping/update it that happens.

Comment: @VinRaghav If pressing the power button turned it back on and then you were able to see your WiFi card it really sounds like you are experiencing some sort of hardware issue if it keeps happening like that.  Holding in the power button for 30 seconds can put the laptop through a power reset and sometimes fix things.  But, experiencing it over and over there is something wrong like heating issue, etc.  I would say get your laptop fully diagnosed.